# Draw x*y=1 on surface

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to draw a line on the surface from x*y=1. How do i do that?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
title={$f(x,y)=x+y$}, 
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
xmin=0, xmax=2,
ymin=0, ymax=2,
zmin=0, zmax=4,
3d box=complete,]
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:2] 
{x+y};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: - Could you provide a complete MWE? - Your question is not entirely clear. What do you obtain now, and what do you want to obtain? `xy=1` is a hyperbola, not a line.

Comment: if you want to draw a line which satisfies x*y = 1, you can use `\addplot3[contour gnuplot={levels=0,labels=false}] {x*y-1};`. It solves the equation `0 = f(x,y) = x*y-1` numerically. But I do not understand what you want to achieve with the plane `x+y`.

Comment: I wanted to show the inequality of the geometric and the arithmetic mean for two variables that it assumes its global minimum at (1,1). Therfor i wantet to plot f(x)=x+y and mark the points M={(x,y)\in R^2 : x*y=1, x,y>0} on the plot f(x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you plan to show a surface plot f(x,y) = x+y and the contour 1= g(x,y) = x* y, but drawn *into* the surface plot, i.e. you want to draw the line {(x,y, x+y) | x*y=1 }. Is that correct?

This can be done as follows:

Solution 1: using a normal surface plot and an overlay of the contour stuff. I chose to use the generic approach with "1 = g(x,y)" here, in the hope that someone might find the approach useful even if he chooses he different g:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
title={$f(x,y)=x+y$}, 
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
xmin=0, xmax=2,
ymin=0, ymax=2,
zmin=0, zmax=4,
%view={0}{90},
3d box=complete,]
\addplot3[
    surf,
    domain=0:2] 
{x+y};

%\addplot3[domain=0:2,draw=none,contour gnuplot={file=contourxy1,levels=1}] {x*y};

\addplot3[black] table[z expr=x+y] {contourxy1.table};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

First, I computed the line 1 = g(x,y) = x*y and wrote the resulting coordinates into a file `contourxy1.table`. To this end, I invoked

```
\addplot3[domain=0:2,draw=none,contour gnuplot={file=contourxy1,levels=1}] {x*y};
```

which is not part of the final output. Then, I loaded this file and modified its Z coordinate such that it is mapped back into f(x,y) = x+y.

This solution works in most cases, but keep in mind that pgfplots cannot really determine which of the involved lines is on top of the other.

Solution 2. An alternative solution is to use a filled contour plot, even if it just has two colors in the end:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
title={$f(x,y)=x+y$}, 
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
xmin=0, xmax=2,
ymin=0, ymax=2,
zmin=0, zmax=4,
colormap={zwocolor}{color=(green!50!black) color=(yellow)},
3d box=complete,]
\addplot3[
    contour filled={levels=1}, 
    point meta={x*y}, 
    domain=0:2] 
{x+y};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the first solution, i get error with the command \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} or could you send me the data contourxy1.table

Comment: This merely indicates that I use a different version that you do. Try to insert `1.14` or some older version. Note that `pgfplots` tells you which line is suitable (in the `log file). If all fails: comment out that line.

Comment: Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'contourxy1.table' in 'searto the pgfplotstable manual for details). ...ack] table[z expr=x+y] {contourxy1.table};

Comment: the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been filtered away)

Comment: note that `\addplot gnuplot` requires 1. an installation of `gnuplot` and 2. you need to invoke `pdflatex -shell-escape`. It is the only plot handler with this special semantics